# Make someone run out of patience

Tags: phrase-requests

If you  **keep trying someone's patience**, eventually they will **run out of patience and do something** to punish you. What is your "negative achievement" called at this stage? You have managed to make some people lose their patience. I'm looking for an equivalent phrase for "**make someone lose their patience**".

An example can be a grown-up child living with his parents who keeps being lazy and annoying the parents till they lose their patience and ask him to leave. What has this child done to his parents?

Comment: "*the last straw* that broken the camel's back": http://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/last+straw

Comment: @SvenYargs sounds like an answer

Comment: You have **exhausted** their patience. You gave them "more than they could put up with". If you were a guest, you "overstayed your welcome".

Comment: @BrianHitchcock has it (+1). You can also say, "*I've* ***had it with*** *you and your pesky questions*". ;-)

Answer (score 2):

It's not a phrase, but in a word the child has *exasperated* the parents, where the relevant meaning of *exasperate* is, according to *Merriam-Webster's Eleventh Collegiate Dictionary* (2003), "to cause irritation or annoyance to."

Comment: "Exasperate" is indeed the verb you are looking for.

Answer (score 0):

**put/set someone on edge**

**drive someone to the brink**

**to do (someone's) head in** Brit to upset, annoy, or exasperate someone (slang)

**drive somebody crazy** (slang)

could help